# Вызов события onMouseClicked на заполненной панели

Tags: java, gui, javafx, ui

Каким образом можно перехватить событие нажатия кнопки мыши на панель в том месте, где уже расположен какой-то элемент? В моём случае гораздо проще сделать именно так, чем присваивать каждому элементу слушатель нажатия кнопки. На панели слишком много элементов для этого, и мне проще вычислить нужный мне элемент по координатам, чем мучатся с кучей циклов и передачей слушателей как аргументов.
[image: Моя панель]

Answer (score 1):

Просто вешайте лисенер на панельку и все. И когда будете перехватывать событие, в поле `target` будет объект, на который произошло нажатие.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();

        Label lbl = new Label("click me!");
        lbl.setStyle("-fx-border-color : red; -fx-border-width : 2px");

        anchorPane.setOnMouseClicked(System.out::println); // при нажатии на лейбл в поле таргет будет ссылка на этот лейбл

        anchorPane.getChildren().add(lbl);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(lbl, 50.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(lbl, 50.0);

        pane.setCenter(anchorPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Странно. Документация гласит, что getTarget возвращает EventHandler. В, общем-то, это так и есть. Но для меня было неожиданностью то, что его можно привести к типу Node, а там уже и конкретному типу элемента. Только я не понял, как вам удалось услышать событие нажатия на место, где есть другой элемент. Мне не в какую не удаётся сделать это с помощью setOnMouseClicked. Зато эту задачу удалось провернуть с помощью addEventFilter. Он перехватывает все события без исключения и не мешает перехватывать их дочерним элементам. Подредактирую вопрос и доотвечу на него теперь сам. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

На `Swing` я делал так:

```
public class Panel extends JPanel {
    private final int CELL_SIZE = 50;

    public Panel() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // Получаем координаты клика
                int y = e.getY() / CELL_SIZE;
                int x = e.getX() / CELL_SIZE;

                // Обработка координат
                // ...

                // ...
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Что-то аналогичное должно быть и на `JavaFX`.